# How to enable Bluetooth with a button OSX

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Is it possible to enable Bluetooth (with Discoverability on), using a button on macOS? Or enable it when an application opens? I've looked around online for a solution but everything directs towards iPhone and iOS Development rather than anything on the Mac side. Everything that is geared towards iOS also states that it is not possible on the mobile devices, but it is possible to display an alert notifying the user to turn on their Bluetooth to use their accessories. Is any alert type possible?

**Edit:** The closest I could get to this was opening the Bluetooth pane of the System Preferences programmatically.

Comment: out of all of the results i've received i've never obtained that one. i'm looking to distribute this application to more than one person, would the command line tool have to be installed on their macs or just into the program itself or how can this communicate with it? @Larme

Comment: You may want to look into http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/. The API is private, so it would never work on the App Store, but you may be able to get it to work.

Comment: yeah yeah, i understand that @RyanCollins. Larme linked me to it. read what I asked though, I'm distributing this program locally, rather than publicly, so that's all good, I'm just wondering if this command line tool would need to be installed on every laptop or just into the program somehow itself..? thanks!

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a private API.

Add the following to your bridging header:

```
void IOBluetoothPreferenceSetControllerPowerState(int);
```

And call it with `1` to enable or `0` to disable:

```
func setBluetooth(on: Bool) {
    IOBluetoothPreferenceSetControllerPowerState(on ? 1 : 0)
}

setBluetooth(on: true)
```

Don't forget to `import IOBluetooth` in your Swift file.

To get the current status use `int IOBluetoothPreferenceGetControllerPowerState();`

Comment: so this is using the blueutil api? couldn't i just perform a shell script instead?

Comment: No, this is using the IOBluetooth framework. The blueutil also uses this

Comment: is this runnable in playground?

Comment: Unfortunately no because you can't create bridging headers in playgrounds but you can create a simple command line mac app, add a bridging header and the above to your main.swift file

Comment: i get an immutable value error when I try to do an if statement to enable/disable bluetooth. how can I make this work?

Comment: I understand now, I wasn't even returning a bool before performing the button task. Thanks!

Comment: This only works on your program, when implemented into mine it mentions it's an unresolved identifier. This is the `GetControllerPowerState` function.

Comment: That's because you have to add the bridging header, take a look at the build settings under Objective-C bridging header

Comment: That is what I added. I've had that and it recognizes the first command but not the second.

Comment: You have to add `int IOBluetoothPreferenceGetControllerPowerState();` to your bridging header

Comment: Does this still work on macOS Ventura on Apple silicon Macs?